# Numpy is there a reverse broadcast?

Tags: numpy

```py
import numpy as np
x0 = np.random.randn(7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
x1 = np.random.randn(9, 1, 11)
y = x0 + x1
print(y.shape)
# (7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
```

as shown above, broadcasting in numpy allows addition of arrays with different shapes. I'd like to know if there is a reverse operation, that sum axes in `y` so that the output is the same shape with `x1`. Currently I need to use two `add.reduce`:

```py
interm = np.add.reduce(y, axis=(0, 1)) # sum all leading axes
result = np.add.reduce(interm, axis=-2, keepdims=True) # sum remaining singleton axes
print(result.shape == x1.shape)
# True
```

Is there a single function that does that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still two steps, but you can first [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) on all 3 axes, then [`reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html):

```
out = np.sum(y, axis=(0, 1, 3)).reshape(x1.shape)
# or
# out = np.add.reduce(y, axis=(0, 1, 3)).reshape(x1.shape)

out.shape
# (9, 1, 11)

np.allclose(out, result)
# True
```